# How to compile c++ code with boost lib? on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

I used headers shown above.
Cannot find help on Boost Official website.

Comment: You will have to show how your attempt failed -- did you get undeclared functions; in which you are missing some headers, or was there a link error -- some of the boost functions require linking to a shared library

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming no errors in your code, you need to link the correct boost libraries: boost_thread, boost_system, and boost_date_time are the ones you've referenced, so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
int main()
{
}
```

This program compiles with the following command:

```
g++ -o test test.cc -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread
```